# Parallels can't open/update although my Mac has an Internet connection

Tags: parallels-desktop

I tried to update Parallels but I could not activate it because it says there is no Internet connection. I have an Internet connection on my Mac, but I cannot even open Parallels.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If no one has an answer, you can edit this to include some details like what version of macos or parallels you have installed as described in [ask]

Comment: If Parallels won't even open that points to a likely issue with the program itself. Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing?